# Python file input (write mode) issue with JSON

Tags: python, json, file-handling

I'm learning Python and I'm following official documentation from:

> Section: ***[7.2.2. Saving structured data with json](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#saving-structured-data-with-json)*** for Python 3

I'm testing the `json.dump()` function to dump my python set into a file pointer:

```
>>> response = {"success": True, "data": ["test", "array", "response"]}
>>> response
{'success': True, 'data': ['test', 'array', 'response']}
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(response)
'{"success": true, "data": ["test", "array", "response"]}'
>>> f = open('testfile.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8')
>>> f
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='testfile.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>> json.dump(response, f)
```

The file `testfile.txt` already exists in my working directory and even if it didn't, statement `f = open('testfile.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8')` would have re-create it, truncated.

The `json.dumps(response)` converts my `response` set into a valid JSON object, so that's fine.

Problem is when I use the `json.dumps(response, f)` method, which actually updates my `testfile.txt`, but it gets truncated.

I've managed to do a reverse workaround like:

```
>>> f = open('testfile.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8')
>>> f.write(json.dumps(response));
56
>>>
```

After which the contents of my `testfile.txt` become as expected:

```
{"success": true, "data": ["test", "array", "response"]}
```

Even, this approach works too:

```
>>> json.dump(response, open('testfile.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8'))
```

Why does this approach fail?:

```
>>> f = open('testfile.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8')
>>> json.dump(response, f)
```

Note that I don't get any errors from the console; just a truncated file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you aren't exiting the interactive prompt to check the file. Close the file to flush it:

```
f.close()
```

It will close if you exit the interactive prompt as well.